# Can I automatically join a server when a slot is free?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I am playing Call of Duty - Modern Warfare in multiplayer mode on **PC** and play most of the time on a specific server that is often full. I have sometimes to hit `Refresh` during 10-20 minutes before I can join.

Is there a way to automatically connect this server when a slot is freeing?
By any mean, a software, a script in Call of Duty 4, a web app...

Comment: Is this for the PC?

Comment: @Earlz, yes for PC. Edited my post to mention it.

Comment: Not likely.  The server browser has very limited features and automatic joining is not one of them.  Still PO'ed that pinging servers is still broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed an application to watch a server (you can see the server map currently played, the players...). It is located in the systray and it provides an option to automatically join a server when it detects a free slot.

See the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Otiel/CoDServerWatcher).

Answer (score 1):

With Call of Duty 4 on PC, there is no apparent way to do so - I've been playing a few years and have yet to figure out some way. Unfortunately the server browser is very limited in what it can do. So your only choice is to add it to your favourites and keep hitting that refresh button.

Unless someone makes a mod for it, this won't get changed. Development has LONG stopped. To my knowledge and googling abilities - no mod exists for it.